# beanstalk application health turns red

Tags: web-services, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have an app which works perfectly on an ubuntu ec2 micro instance, I've attempted to get it working on beanstalk and for some reason why I load up the page and the 70+ assets are loading (it's in dev mode), it ends up crashing half way through. The load balancer seems to automatically transition it to yellow followed by red for a few seconds, then it goes back to green, as soon as it transitions all the assets fail w/ 503 error. When I look at the monitoring all the levels are low, the CPU hardly spikes at all.

What I want to know is how I troubleshoot what is causing the load balancer to start returning 503's. I'm also wondering how that is even possible, isn't the idea of beanstalk to allow the app to auto-scale?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would look at the 503's closely to see if they are generated by the ELB or the backend instances? This is closely related to the Unhealthyhost count metric on CloudWatch. Following up to that I would recommend revisiting health check config on the load balancer.

Comment: I am commenting a bit late in the hope that this saves someone some time.  I had this issue and solved it by "revisiting health check config on the load balancer".  After doing so, I quickly realized that I'd renamed the page of the "Application Health Check URL".  Correcting this quickly solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For me that was because of incorrectly configured health check.

Go to logs and find something related to "ELB-HealthChecker". You will see four numbers, while the left one is http status code. It has to be 200. Also, if your health check URL returns body, make sure "Content-Length" header value is zero.